# How to type hinte higher-order functions in python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

In the following code:

```
def b(i: int) -> int:
    return i

def a(i: int, b: ?) -> int:
    return i + b(i)

print(a(1, b))
```

How do we type hinting the function `b: ?` that is a parameter of `a`?  Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`typing.Callable` generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) to indicate you expect a function that takes a single integer argument, returning an integer:

```
from typing import Callable

def a(i: int, b: Callable[[int], int]) -> int:
    return i + b(i)
```

`Callable[...]` takes two arguments, the first a list of argument types, the second the return type.

Comment: What about if the parameter is optional?

Comment: @CervEd `Callable` is quite primitive. Use a [`Protocol`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/ ) subclass with a `__call__` method to model a function with a more complex signature like keyword arguments.

Comment: Also see the [mypy docs on callback protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols)